# Angular search filter doesn't search in entire table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

The problem is the search filter only finds records from the current page and I want it to find record from entire table. How can I do that?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search By Any..." ng-model="search.$"/>
<table dir="ltr" width="477" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('name')">User</a></th>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('contentType')">Content Type</a></th>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('contentName')">Content Name</a></th>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('startTime')">Start Time</a></th>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('endTime')">End Time</a></th>
            <th><a style="font-size: 16px;" href="#" ng-click="changeSort('duration')">Duration(In Secs)</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords | filter: search | orderBy:sort:reverse track by $index">
            <td>{{record.user}}</td>
            <td>{{record.contentType}}</td>
            <td>{{record.contentName}}</td>
            <td>{{record.startTime}}</td>
            <td>{{record.endTime}}</td>
            <td>{{record.duration}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<pagination class="pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;" num-pages="numPages()" current-page="currentPage" on-select-page="pageChanged(page)"></pagination>
```

Angular code:

```
angular.module("contentViewStatusApp")
       .controller("contentViewStatusController", function($scope, contentViewStatusService){
    $scope.records = contentViewStatusService.list();
    $scope.currentPage = 1
    $scope.numPerPage = 10
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.numPages = function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.records.length / $scope.numPerPage);
    };
    $scope.changeSort = function(value){
        if ($scope.sort == value){
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
            return;
        }
        $scope.sort = value;
        $scope.reverse = false;
    }
    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function(){
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage), end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
        $scope.filteredRecords = $scope.records.slice(begin, end);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do pagination using filters instead of creating another array. This way it would search through the entire array before being filtered down.

[**This page**](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html) shows an example of pagination with filters.

Then you could just have the search query first and it should search through the whole array.

**Update**

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/2c4xx42e/2/) one with pagination that updates based on search text.

It watches the search text and updates the page range after filtering:

```
$scope.$watch('searchText.name', function (v) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pages = $scope.range();
});
```

Then the `pageCount` is updated based on the filtered results:

```
$scope.pageCount = function () {
    var pages = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.searchText);
    return Math.ceil(pages.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I am doing it this way: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2c4xx42e/) but the only problem is the pagination doesnt get updated when the page size reduce, can u please help

Comment: Here's one with pagination that updates http://jsfiddle.net/2c4xx42e/1/ .. the only thing it's missing is the current page doesn't stay in the middle of the range.. but it's nice overall

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I agree with @agreco but I think you have to define filtered records in such way that it always works with your `search.$ model`. So to do this please have a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLots5zd/).

Hope this solves your problem. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @param name A string to be matched against the input
 */
getEmp(name: string, input: string): boolean {
    var myFlag = true;
    if(input.length == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {      
        for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          if(name.charAt(j) == input.charAt(i)) {
            j++;
            myFlag = true;  
          } else {
            myFlag = false;
          }
        }
        return myFlag;
    }
}
```